# iTunes Gift Card vs. Family Sharing

Tags: itunes, apple-id

I am a member of a family sharing plan on iTunes. In order to not charge my partner when I make a purchase, I purchased an iTunes gift card and gave it to myself - $200. I was able to make two purchases against the gift card, but now every time I try to purchase music, even though I can see I have $180.02 balance, I get the pop-up box that says I need the family organizer to authorize. I don't seem to be able to access my own gift card to make my own purchases. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Are you designated as an organizer or parent in that family group?  See [this Apple article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088) to ensure it's been setup correctly for your family.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Apple support. We had a similar issue on our family account recently and needed their help to assist. Nothing we were willing to try got the gift balance back in to the rotation.

It's supposed to charge the balance for most but not all purchases and my guess is a subscription or something that went to the card got the balance set aside.

Answer (score 0):

(From personal experience with this problem) I'm pretty sure that there is a setting in iOS (maybe appleid or iCloud online for a computer) that changes which account will get charged. Or, you will have to put in the organizers password and then it'll unlock purchases(?)

I'm sorry, I'm not exactly sure which way to fix it, I had this problem a long time ago.